# VBA Excel - Create a Macro Button to E-mail .xlsm as an .xlsm Whilw Specifiying Recipient

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a protected form with two Form Control buttons allowing the user to send the form to one of two people without saving the form. I am currently using:

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show

I would like to know if there is a way to designate specific email addresses as opposed to the user needing to type them in? Furthermore, I need the form to remain a macro-enabled spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are three arguments that you can set for the `xlDialogSendMail` Dialog box

- *Arg1* = recipients
- *Arg2* = subject
- *Arg3* = return_receipt

To set recipients, you would then do...

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show("email_address@so.com")
```

Source: [Built-In Dialog Box Argument Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221648%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Cool! If that works for you, you can click the checkbox by the answer to accept it.